# Why puppetlabs-firewall module does not work - Error 500 . Unacceptable location

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install puppetlabs-firewall on my Puppet managed nodes. There are 3 environments, test/uat/production. I manage modules on these using r10k.

When on an agent, I run "puppet agent -t" and the error I am getting back is the below:

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'test'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Unacceptable location. The name 'firewall' is unacceptable in file '/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/modules/iptables_new/manifests/init.pp' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/modules/iptables_new/manifests/init.pp, line: 33, column: 1) on node postfix.example.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What does "unacceptable location" mean? I haven't changed anything from the puppetlabs-firewall module. I just cloned it and renamed.

Below is the environments.conf on the Puppet master:

```
root@puppet:/home/puppet/environments# cat environments.conf
modulepath = site:modules:$basemodulepath
manifest = manifests/site.pp
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Is  `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/modules/iptables_new/manifests/init.pp` something you wrote? If so, can you show us the code?

Comment: After a lot of digging on the wrong path, I found out that after version 5.5 of Puppet, a class name has to be derived from the module name. More information is found here: https://groups.google.com/g/puppet-users/c/nxbwCvWrgMI?pli=1 .

Given this, I changed the module name to firewall and it worked!